# [C]Reverse array with only pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I tried to reverse an array using only pointers. The program runs without any errors but it doesn't reverse the array. What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10
void arrayReverseOutput(int * arr);
void arrayInput(int * arr);
void printArray(int * arr);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[SIZE] = { 0 };
    arrayInput(arr);
    arrayReverseOutput(arr);
    printArray(arr);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void arrayInput(int * arr){
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        scanf("%d",(arr+i));
    }
}

void arrayReverseOutput(int * arr){
    int i = 0;
    int k = SIZE-1;
    int temp = 0;


    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        temp = *(arr+i);
        *(arr+i) = *(arr + k);
        *(arr + k) = temp;
        k--;
    }
}

void printArray(int * arr){
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        printf("%d ", *(arr+i));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using only pointers"?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you are actually reversing the array *twice*, negating any changes achieved by swapping places.

Loop over only half of the array while swapping the elements, like

```
 for (i = 0; i < SIZE/2; i++)
```

Comment: 'you are actually reversing the array twice' - you knew that before opening the question, yes?  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 pointers to do so

```
void arrayReverseOutput(int *head, int *tail)
{
    int temp = 0;

    do
    {
        temp = *tail;
        *tail = *head;
        *head = temp;
    }
    while (head++ < tail--);
}
```

Complete code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10
void arrayReverseOutput(int *head, int *tail);
void arrayInput(int * arr);
void printArray(int * arr);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[SIZE] = { 0 };
    arrayInput(arr);
    arrayReverseOutput(arr, &arr[SIZE - 1]);
    printArray(arr);

    return 0;
}

void arrayInput(int * arr)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", (arr + i));
    }
}

void arrayReverseOutput(int *head, int *tail)
{
    int temp = 0;

    do
    {
        temp = *tail;
        *tail = *head;
        *head = temp;
    }
    while (head++ < tail--);
}

void printArray(int * arr)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
    }
}
```